# Auto Ajdust Column Width of selection

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to create a shortcut (via a custom add-in) that will take the selection range currently selected and Auto Fit column width. However, I am struggling on how to conceptualize taking the current selection, from there then taking all these columns?

Appreciate any help, I am trying to start using VBA in an optimal manner, so any good pointers for correct programming would be appreciated.

Comment: `Selection.EntireColumn`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @Tim Williams for the simple solution. My Sub looks like this:

```
Sub AutoFitColumnWidth()

    Selection.Columns.AutoFit

End Sub
```